# Node.js: Read from a file, query database and write to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have a process where i get a csv file with unique ids. i want to do the following

1. Read from the file( for ex. a file containing all user ids)
2. Query database (get more details of each user from database)
3. Write to another file with results received from database (write additional details to a new file)

I have the following code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const config = require('config');
const db = require('../../app/db');
async function transform(sheet) {
  let rs = fs.createReadStream(sheet.path, {encoding: config.get('csv.encoding')});
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: rs,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });
  for await(const line of rl) {
    //query database, get additional information
    // const { rows } = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [line[0]]);
    //write to file
  }
}
module.exports = transform;
```

I am not sure what would be the most efficient way to do this as my file can contain 10k to 20k records, and i don't want to issue to the database one query at a time.

Any help on how to achieve this will be really great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- SQL (import csv)

  1. COPY csv file TO postgresql table(reference:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html)
  2. SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM imported_csv)
- SQL (csv file as postgresql table)

  1. use file_fdw to read csv file as table(example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/file-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.23.14)
  2. SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM csv_as_pg_table)
- Javascript (create in-memory "Table")

  1. const { rows } = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id')
  2. const id_to_row = id => {...} // Map, binary search, ...
  3. const row = id_to_row(line)